# How do I remove a frequented tag?

Tags: support, tags

When I logged in today I saw a new frequented tag on the right side:

[image]

This causes questions having the 'android' tag to be highlighted. Example of highlighted questions:
[image]

But I don't want that. How do I remove the tag?

Thanks.

Comment: Which page was this on?

Comment: @ChrisF: on the main page.

Comment: I'm only seeing "Favorite" and "Ignored" at the top and then "Recent" underneath the advert. Can you show the image with a bit more context?

Comment: @ChrisF: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you haven't set any "Interesting" or "Ignored" tags. The system is trying to work out what questions you might find interesting based on your previous viewing/answering habits.

If you follow the "set tag preferences" link and set up just one tag in either "Interesting" or "Ignored" the system will use this tag set for highlighting purposes.

Comment: "The system is trying to work out what questions you might find interesting". It is possible to disable this behaviour?

Comment: @gulbrandr - Yes by just setting **one** "Interesting" **or** "Ingored" tag.

Comment: But I don't want to ignore or be interested in anything...

Comment: @fluteflute see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88351.

Answer (score 7):

Seconding the comment by fluteflute, but it needs to be an answer.

Over on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), I'm generally interested in the whole subject matter, so I *do not want any highlighting* nor shading of topics. The fact that I'm coerced into it now is absolutely frustrating.

PLEASE make this a preference, or at least give us the ability to remove these 'frequented' tags. I like the concept, but on such a specific site as [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com), it's exceedingly unnecessary for me.

Not to mention that I think it's horribly flawed. I've answered/asked/edited countless iphone, ipad, ios tagged questions. Yet one day after Lion comes out it's already "frequented" for me? Perhaps it's just the lack of knowledge of how exactly it's determined. And that doesn't help either.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88351.

Comment: Me neither. On Physics.SE, the tag [tag:quantum-mechanics] has been mysteriously highlighted even though I don't understand half the questions. True, I've given some great answers on that tag, but there's only a lot of them since [tag:quantum-mechanics] is the most used tag on the site. And similarly, I don't have any favorite tags, I answer stuff from anything. Dear SE system: PLEASE DO NOT TELL ME WHAT I LIKE!!!