# Why are "etymology" questions on german.sx highlighted for me?

Tags: support, tag-watching, highlighting

Starting a few minutes ago, questions tagged "etymology" are highlighted in blue when I visit [german.sx](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions).

[image]

Yes, I did find the question "[Why do some questions in question lists have a yellow background?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11253)", but I haven't favourited the "etymology" tag, and I haven't asked or answered any questions with that tag. Is this a bug?

EDIT: The hightlighting just disappeared all by itself. Nevertheless, I won't delete the question yet in case the phenomenon returns.

Comment: While you might not be a top user, you've probably answered more questions with this tag than others and so the system flags it as "interesting" to you.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks for your comment. Actually, I haven't answered _any_ questions tagged "etymology". I have edited my question accordingly. (I didn't know the system would patronize me in this way you describe!)

Comment: In the case that you don't have explicit tag preferences, we do try to infer some *implicit* favorite tags, based on activity. I don't know the *exact* rules for that, hence not adding as an answer...

Comment: @Marc: So far I was lucky enough not to get any highlighting based on activity, unless this half-hour intermezzo counts. I would find it annoying to get such _implicit_ favorites (which why I wrote "patronize" above). But maybe it only kicks in if your activity is heavily biased - and mine isn't; then it would be OK. If you find a reference to more detail, please let me know!

Comment: @Hans: Huh, is this the same phenomenon?

Comment: I'll write it up in German next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marc notes in a comment that you can have implicit "frequented" tags. These appear to be triggered by **visiting** a lot of questions with the tag in a relative period of time, and you don't currently have any preferences on that site. I triggered it long ago on Gaming while cleaning shop, [which led to this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/please-let-users-opt-out-of-the-frequented-tag-system).

These are temporary and will go away in due time, it seems - mine went away without me moving my view bias anywhere. But it is possible for it to return if you spend a lot of time on a single tag again. Like Marc, I'm not knowing of the exact rules, but this is still more an answer than a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, in particular for the link to your feature-request. I had seen that request, but only a vague feeling of its existence remained, and I couldn't find it again. EDIT: Ah, I see the answer to your feature-request even offers a workaround. Great!

Comment: Let me point out that I don't have the _slightest_ idea how the system could think I visit "etymology" tagged questions frequently. I just visit _all_ the questions on german.sx, and that's it. (@Grace: I don't expect you to help me out here `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593) for Jeff's formula explanation from six months ago.

Comment: @Troyen: Ah, great link, thanks. (Although with the number X,Y,Z given there, I can't explain what happened.)